# Send something through / by / per / via email?

Tags: prepositions

What would be the correct preposition:

> "I will send all further details ____ email" ?

I would guess '**through**' or '**by**' or '**per**' or '**via**' all sound kind of right, but I'm not sure what's the best choice.

Comment: Any of them but *per*.  Your choice.  (*per* means “as specified by”  or “according to” and so doesn’t fit in your senrence)

Comment: "by" is the simplest, most straight-forward, and most common.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but you could just say: _I will email all further details._

Answer (score 3):

If it were me, I'd use either "by" or "via," and of those two, I'd tend to lean a little more toward "via." You're basically saying you're sending the details "by way of" email and I think that would make the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use ‘by’. I would prefer this to ‘via’ and ‘per’ which as Latin words I would only use in the specific niches they have occupied in English (e.g. London via Birmingham, £1000 per week). ‘Through’ has also a connotation of movement in addition to that of indicating an agent, which jars with me.

I know it’s been criticized, but “familiar rather than unfamiliar, short rather than long, and Anglo-Saxon rather than Latin” work for me here.